How can I revert back to HDMI view without access to raspberry pi display?
I've been working with my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B , primarily using a HDMI and monitor, but I have reached a point where I now require to use a 3.5" TFT Touchscreen.
I cloned the GitHub repo LCD-show into my file system and corrected all the permissions necessary. I then ran the corresponding script for my LCD screen and the Pi rebooted however, something has either corrupted or broken, I'm not sure, as it does not load up at all - the screen is on, the pi is working but never loads up.
I have tried inserting the SD card into my laptop to enter config files but altering that file hasn't worked. I can't run ./LCD-hdmi because I don't have access to anything on my Pi. All I have is the image on my SD card that I originally flashed with OS
Is there any way to force swap the output back to HDMI so I can have access to my Pi again?

I cloned the GitHub repo which one?
